# Access opencv matrix CV_32S element

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

If I have a matrix of type `CV_32SC1`, what typename should I use in function `Mat::at`?

e.g.

```
Mat X;  // for example eye matrix of size 10,10,and type CV_32SC1
X.at<??????>(1,1)=5;
```

How can I find the typename for other matrix types?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The general rule for Matrices typenames in OpenCV is:

```
 CV_<bit_depth>(S|U|F)C<number_of_channels>

S = Signed integer
U = Unsigned integer
F = Float
```

So depending on which one of the previous letters (S,U,F) you have, you will be casting `<int>`, `<unsigned integer>` or `<float>`.

Comment: Please actually [read](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/780994) the reviews you are clicking approve on.

Comment: In this case I would prefer <int32_t> to <int>, as the C++ standard does not specify the bit-size of integral types.

Comment: There is no CV_32U* type.  But you can still use `X.at<uint32_t>(i,j)` if your CV_32SC1 array actually contains unsigned values.

Answer (score 4):

CV_32SC1 is a 1 Channel of Signed 32 bit integer, then I think that `X.at<int>()` should do.

Mat already 'knows' how to address a pixel, the type just cast the bits to the C++ value you require for the expression evaluation.

I found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) some explanation about the notation.

Comment: Not quite true. with `at<T>`, the addressing in x direction is based entirely on the size of T . If your matrix is CV_8UC3, then `X.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,2)` will get you the third pixel on the first row; but `X.at<uint8_t>(0,2*3+1)` will give you the second channel of the same pixel (i.e the same byte as  `X.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,2)[1]`
Because of this, the pitch in x direction is based on a compile-time constant `sizeof(T)` rather than on a value calculated from the type stored in the Mat object, which makes a considerable difference in performance.  It also supports 'flat' view of multi-channel arrs.